# WTL 9 and visual studio 2013 community edition

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, wtl

I've tried compiling a few of the WTL 9 sample applications with visual studio 2013 community edition.

Since community edition reported to be a free version of professional, should this work?

First line of compiler output:

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlwin.h(2084): error C2065: 'HMONITOR' : undeclared identifier

Express 2013 needed  [these hacks](https://barkingbogart.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/how-to-use-wtl-9-0-with-visual-studio-express-2013/), is the same needed for community edition?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

Comment: Modified WINVER to 0x0501 in stdafx.h, works, thanks Hans

Answer (score 1):

Pleased to report the samples compile in 2013 Community Edition
See Nenads response to my question
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.windows.wtl/16893/focus=16895
https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/wtl/conversations/messages/16691